# NextJS14 link to state or link and state

Tags: next.js

There is a button group with a white background, and each button changes its URL when clicked. Additionally, the currently selected button is colored.

In this situation, the state of the button was managed through useState, and when the button was clicked,

1. Change the value of the button through setState
2. Change the URL path through the router

I took two actions like this.

The question that arose at that time was that since URLs and buttons can be mapped anyway, wouldn't it be functionally the same if you just change the URL when you click the button, read the URL, and give the value back to the button? Then, wouldn’t it be possible to replace the existing two actions with one action? I thought.

So, after doing a little research, I read that changing the url and re-managing the button's state through the value is not an immediate response, and that changing the url and button state separately as seen in the video is more interactive. (This is not a credible article.) In fact, for this reason, I am wondering if it would be better to change both at the same time, rather than just changing the url, receiving the value, and assigning the button value.

What is the difference between these methods and which is better?

```
export default function GatherLocationFilter({
  searchParam,
}: IGatherLocationFilter) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const defaultLocation = convertLocationLangTo(searchParam, "kr");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<ActiveLocation>(
    defaultLocation || "전체"
  );

  const onClickButton = (locationType: ActiveLocation) => {
    setLocation(locationType);
    const url =
      locationType === "전체"
        ? "/gather"
        : createUrlWithLocation(
            "/gather",
            convertLocationLangTo(locationType, "en")
          );
    router.replace(url);
  };
```